# android eclipse launch intent for map with an address instead of latitude and longitude

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, maps, street-address

I know you can start an intent to open google maps with latitude and longitude, but what if you just have an address (such as 555 south green street St.Louis Missouri) and would like to show a map that way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not completely sure, maybe something like this?

```
String uri = "geo:0,0?q=my+street+address";
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

Comment: Yes this works.  I will just have to figure out how to add a point from address to finish the code.  Thank you very much.